# Can't drop an empty database in mariadb

Tags: mariadb

As the title says, I cannot drop an empty database. In PHPMyAdmin, the request says that it times out and from running it in bash it just goes on until I cancel it with `mysqladmin -u root -p kill <pid>`. Running `use panel;` then `show tables;` just displays `Empty set (0.001 sec)` What can I do to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: can u try 'show databases;' can u see that db from that list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can remember correctly, I fixed it by setting the innodb_force_recovorey level or I just purged the mariadb package and restored from `.sql` files